# Cuda doesn't calculate what it is expected to, just silently ignores my code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I'm encountering a very strange problem: Mu 9800GT doesnt seem to calculate at all.
I've tried all hello-worlds i've found in the internet, here's one of them:

this program creates 1..100 array on hosts, sends it to device, calculates a square of each value, returns it to host, prints the results.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)
{
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
if (idx<N) a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];
}

// main routine that executes on the host
int main(void)
{
float *a_h, *a_d; // Pointer to host & device arrays
const int N = 100; // Number of elements in arrays
size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
a_h = (float *)malloc(size); // Allocate array on host
cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size); // Allocate array on device
// Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
// Do calculation on device:
int block_size = 4;
int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
square_array <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (a_d, N);
// Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
// Print results
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d %f\n", i, a_h[i]);
// Cleanup
free(a_h); cudaFree(a_d);
}
```

so the output is expected to be:

> 1 1.000
>
> 2 4.000
>
> 3 9.000
>
> 4 16.000

..
I swear back in 2009 it worked perfectly (vista 32, deviceemu)

now i get output:

> 1 1.000
>
> 2 2.000
>
> 3 3.000
>
> 4 4.000

so my card doesnt do anything. What can be the problem?
Configuration is:
win7x64
visual studio 2010 32bit
cuda toolkit 3.2 64bit

compilation settings: cuda 3.2 toolkit, 32-bit target platform, deviceemu or not - doesnt matter, the results are the same.

i also tried it on my vmware xp(32bit) visual studio 2008. the result is the same.

Please help me, i barely made the programe to compile, now i need it to work.

You can also view my project with all it needs from [my post at nvidia forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?act=attach&type=post&id=24060) ( 2.7 kb)

Thanks, Ilya

Comment: Hey Ilya,

I am facing the exact same problem, I implemented it first on my CUDA compliant desktop computer where it works perfectly, and when I moved onto the super computer, I am getting the exact same output.

WHat do you reckon I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code produces the intended results on my Linux system so I would suggest checking the error codes returned by `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` to ensure there are no silent driver/runtime errors.  For example

```
cudaError_t error = cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printf("error status: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
```

should print

```
error status: no error
```

if the call is successful.

Also, I believe device emulation was deprecated in CUDA 3.0 and removed entirely in CUDA 3.1.  I don't know if that's related to your problem though.

To compile several files you'd just do something like this

```
$nvcc -c foo.cu
$nvcc -c bar.cu
$nvcc -o foobar foo.o bar.o
```

alternatively, you can do the linking in the last step with `g++` like so

```
$g++ -o foobar foo.o bar.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

Comment: yep, figured that out myself :) error  cudaErrorInsufficientDriver = CUDA runtime is newer than driver. 
will now remove all drivers, reboot and install them from scratch

Comment: please post your g++ compilation string here and i'll mark this as an answer. (I actually need it to be run under ubuntu, but have no idea how to compile more than 1 file :))