# CUDA 4.2. toolbox & VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I am trying to compile Cuda SDK examples but I am getting "MSB3721 error" since "nvcc" is "exited with code 1". Complete output:

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   4.2.targets(361,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" -I"./" -I"../../common/inc"
>   -I"../../../shared/inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include"  -G  --keep-dir "x64\Debug" -maxrregcount=0
>   --machine 64 --compile  -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MTd  " -o "x64/Debug/bandwidthTest.cu.obj" "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK
>   4.2\C\src\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu"" exited with code 1."

Cuda toolkit 4.2 is used on Win7 x64 Ultimate system with VS2010 Ultimate. 
The error remains when the "win32" option in "Configuration management" is used.

Are there any suggestions?

!!!!! Finally after reading all available NVIDIA manuals about "Getting started with CUDA" after reinstalling Win7+VS2010+CUDA drivers more than 10 times after building a new computer (Z77 mobo + i7 + GTX550Ti) and after waiting for months the NVIDIA forum resurrection I found out that the problem with the nvcc build error "exited with code 1" was disappeared when the "Run as administrator" option was selected on the VS2010 shortcut on my desktop!!!!!!
Although I was using an administrator account (the only account on the PC) it was impossible to build any of the CUDA Examples. The executables were running without any problem but I couldn't build the source code using VS2010!

!!!!!Thank you all for your support!!!!!

Comment: Is there any more information in the build log?

Comment: When you create a new solution, choose (instead of C++ Application/whatever) NVIDIA -> CUDA -> CUDA 4.2 Runtime and try running the newly created project. Does it work?

Comment: When I create a new solution it doesn't work and there is again exit code 1 error

Comment: I have installed CUDA 5.0 Release and I am still getting the same error?

Comment: nvcc must be printing errors that you are not including. What is displayed in the output window?

Comment: Thank you harrism for the support...

Answer (score 1):

I would try to start from scratch. Remove CUDA, Nsight, and Visual Studio. Reboot. Manually remove any program folders that might be left. I can't guarantee that it's safe to remove these, but if any other NVIDIA or Microsoft products break because of this, I'd just fix those after having fixed CUDA:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Parallel Nsight 2.1
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Parallel Nsight Monitor 2.1
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit
```

Manually remove any left over app data folders:

```
C:\Users\<your user folder>\AppData\Roaming\NVIDIA
C:\Users\<your user folder>\AppData\Roaming\NVIDIA Corporation
```

You might want to look for registry keys as well.

Then reinstall everything. Nsight comes with CUDA, so I'd first install VS then Nsight. That should be all that is required. Then, create a CUDA project from scratch.

Comment: Note you must change `C:\Users\Roger` with your current windows home folder.

Comment: Are there any possibilities to face this problems because of VS2010 sp1 installation? I have not tried the compilation of any CUDA projects before sp1 installation...

Comment: I have tried removing VS2010, CUDA & NSight and installing again without any results.  I will try formatting my new SSD and start installing my system, VS2010 & CUDA from scratch...

Comment: VS service pack 1 is not a problem. I'm using almost the same configuration as you (Cuda 4.2, Win7 x64 Prof SP1, VS2010 Ultimate SP1) and everything works fine for me.

Comment: I have formatted my disk and installed everything again!"exited with code 1" error remains! I will try to see if I could have any luck at the Nvidia forum when it will be back up and running! Also I hope that it is not my ancient mobo issue (MSI P6N platinum with Nvidia 650 SLI chipset)

Comment: @Panik: Could you outline the method which you use for creating the CUDA project from scratch?

Comment: @Roger Dahl Thank you very much for your support!! I am not creating a new CUDA project from scratch! I am trying to compile some of the sample projects included in the CUDA SDK. Do you believe that I should try something like "step 3" from http://www.stevenmarkford.com/installing-nvidia-cuda-with-visual-studio-2010/ ???

Comment: @Panik: Yes, try step 3 at stevenmarkford.com. Also, if you haven't tried it already, download the latest SDK (step 3 on the [CUDA download site](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cuda/cuda-downloads.html)).

Comment: @Roger Dahl: I have tried the latest SDK as well as the prereleased version of CUDA 5 drivers + SDK. Unfortunately the builder is exiting with the "code 1" message. Do you have any idea where I can find info about these exit codes?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this thread, maybe it helps you with your problem:
[How to Compile CUDA App is Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953326/how-to-compile-cuda-app-is-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately it didn't worked out for me! Thanks anyway!