# Compile error in cuda

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image-processing, cuda

I have a compile error in cuda and I want why this erro happen ? 
I want to Know if my cuda run in 2DArray  for image processing in future

My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;

#define BLOCK_WIDTH 16


__global__ void kernel(int *d_A, size_t pitch, int rows, int cols){
 //compute the row
 int r = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
 //compute the column
  int c = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

  if((r < rows) && (c < cols)){
  //   // update the pointer to point to the beginning of the row
   //int *Row = (int*)((char*)d_A + r*pitch);
  int *Row = (int*)((char*)d_A);
  int elem = Row[c];
  printf("%d ", elem);
  }
  }


 void test(int **A, int rows, int cols){
 int *d_A;
 size_t pitch;

 cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_A, &pitch, sizeof(int)*cols, rows);

 cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, A, sizeof(int)*cols, sizeof(int)*cols, rows,            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 //Define grid and block size
 int Yblocks = rows / BLOCK_WIDTH;
 if(rows % BLOCK_WIDTH) Yblocks++;
 int Xblocks = cols / BLOCK_WIDTH;
  if(cols % BLOCK_WIDTH) Xblocks++;
  //  cout << Yblocks << "," << Xblocks << endl;
 dim3 dimGrid(Yblocks, Xblocks, 1);
 dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_WIDTH, BLOCK_WIDTH, 1);
  //Run kernel
 kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_A, pitch, rows, cols);

cudaMemcpy2D(A, sizeof(int)*cols, d_A, pitch, sizeof(int)*cols, rows,     cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

 cudaFree(&d_A);
 }


int main(){
 int rows = 2;
   int cols = 2;

   int **A;
  A = new int*[rows];
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){ 
   A[i] = new int[cols];
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
     A[i][j] = i+2;
     }

   test(A, rows, cols);

  for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
   for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
     cout << A[i][j] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) delete[] A[i];
    delete[] A;

   return 0;
   }
```

I have in my laptop :
    NVIDIA CUDA sample 7.5 ,
      NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 7.5 ,
      NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit v5(64),
      NVIDIA CUDA Tools SDK v4.0 ,
       NVIDIA GPU computing SDK 4 ,
      NVIDIA Graphic driver 306.94 ,
       NVIDIA Nsigth visual studio edition 5.1.0.10602 ,
       visual studio 2010 ,
       NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS ,
      driver model :WDDM 1.1 ,
      DDI version :10 ,
      windows 7

I have this error

```
   1>------ Build started: Project: 2Dexample, Configuration: Debug Win32 --
  1>Build started 8/10/2016 6:29:45 AM.
  1>InitializeBuildStatus:
   1>  Touching "Debug\2Dexample.unsuccessfulbuild".
  1>AddCudaCompileDeps:
   1>Skipping target "AddCudaCompileDeps" because all output files are up- to-date with respect to the input files.
 1>AddCudaCompilePropsDeps:
1>Skipping target "AddCudaCompilePropsDeps" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
 1>CudaBuild:
1>  Compiling CUDA source file kernel.cu...
 1>  
 1>  C:\Users\Amany\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\2Dexample\2Dexample>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  - I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G    -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -1  -g   -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o "Debug\kernel.cu.obj" "C:\Users\Amany\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\2Dexample\2Dexample\kernel.cu" 
 1>nvcc : fatal error : Unknown option '1'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.0.targets(592,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G    -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -1  -g   -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o "Debug\kernel.cu.obj" "C:\Users\Amany\Documents\Visual Studio     2010\Projects\2Dexample\2Dexample\kernel.cu"" exited with code -1.
 1>
 1>Build FAILED.
   1>
  1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29
  ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped
```

I try many things but not work:

[How to Compile CUDA App is Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953326/how-to-compile-cuda-app-is-visual-studio-2010)

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/577900/error-msb3721-with-cuda-5-5-and-vs-2010-professional/

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/577900/error-msb3721-with-cuda-5-5-and-vs-2010-professional/

but not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it may be related to this weird value

```
nvcc.exe  .......  --compile -1  .......
nvcc : fatal error : Unknown option '1'
```

Comment: So what I should do  to fix it ??plz